# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() PHP

Tags: php, foreach

**Buenas con todos, estoy empezando en esto de php y html y me sale este error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in : C:\wamp\www\Supermecadooo\Vista\index.php on line 57**

He revisado y no encuentro el error

**Codigo:**

```
<?php 
    require_once("../modelo/producto.php");
    $obj = new Producto;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <title>Supermercado</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body >
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
            <div class = "container" id="navColor">
                <a class="navbar-brand" id="navColor" href="index.php">SUPERMECADOS S.A.</a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navColor">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" id="navColor" varia-current="page" href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navColor" id="navbarDropdown"  role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Mi Cuenta</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mis Compras</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="login.php">Mi Perfil</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Finalizar Sesión</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container" >
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="imagenes/super.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="50"></a>    
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"> <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="Buscar" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Buscar"> </div>
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button> </div>
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"> <button class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Ver Carrito</button> </div>
                    
                </div>
            </form>
        </nav>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="container" >
        <hr>
        
        <section class="main row">
        <?php
            $datos=$obj->ObtenerTodos();
            foreach($datos as $fila){   //Linea 57      
        ?>
            <article class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $fila['imagen']?>" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $fila['nombre']?></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> $ <?php echo $fila['precio']?></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"> <button class="btn btn-outline-dark my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Agregar al Carrito</button> </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <?php } ?>
        </section>
        
    </div>  
    
    <div class="container" >
    <br>
    <hr>
        <footer id="footer">
            <br>SUPERMECADOS S.A.<br>
            ¿Quienes Somos?-Términos y condiciones-Contacto-Políticas<br><br>
        </footer> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El error te esta avisando que `$datos` no es un array u objeto que puedas iterar, realiza un `var_dump($datos);` y agrega a tu pregunta que salida obtienes, por cierto evita por favor colocar texto de relleno que no aporta en nada a la duda expuesta

Comment: ¿Dónde está el método ObtenerTodos()? Parece que no devuelve un valor iterable